# PHP - Closure in class , getting private property

Tags: php

I'm attempting to get a private property from another class using closures, as explained here:

http://ocramius.github.io/blog/accessing-private-php-class-members-without-reflection/

So, I'm trying to get the $wheelCount property.

But I keep getting

```
Fatal error: Cannot access private property Car::$wheelCount
```

So my car class is:

```
class Car
{
    private $wheelCount = 4;    

    public function __construct($wheely)
    {

             echo $wheely->getWheels($this);

    }
}
```

and then

```
   class getThoseWheels
    {

        public function getWheels($that)
        {

            $wheels = Closure::bind($this->getPrivate($that), null, $that);

            var_dump($wheels);


        }

        public function getPrivate($that)
        {
             return $that->wheelCount;
        }
    }
```

which is run:

```
$wheely = new getThoseWheels();

new Car($wheely);
```

Comment: Closures aren't the problem, you're trying to access a private property from another class.

Comment: use a getter, or make it public, why would you want to use a closure anyway?

Comment: Class Car cannot be modified.

Comment: working example from the link of what I'm trying to achieve.  http://3v4l.org/EVQHg

Comment: From that example it is seen that this only works in php 5.4.0 - 5.5.3. So if it create any errors youre running the wrong version of php

Comment: the only difference I can find  in yours and the example is this. So try this and if it doesnt work then I dont know what could. `$wheels = Closure::bind($this->getPrivate, null, $that);`

Comment: @kpp that doesn't work as getPrivate is a method not a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$wheels = Closure::bind($this->getPrivate($that), null, $that);
```

The problem is that you're *executing* `$this->getPrivate()`, and this method is trying to access a `private` property. All this happens before `Closure::bind` is being involved at all. You're supposed to use it like this:

```
$wheels = Closure::bind(function () { return $this->wheels; }, $that, $that);
```

Or possibly:

```
$wheels = Closure::bind([$this, 'getPrivate'], null, $that);
```

I haven't tested this, but at least this has a much better chance of succeeding than your code.

Comment: Your first answer was close. I needed to to that and then:  $wheels = $wheels($that); Thanks